# Default-Severity at jQassistant

Tags: jqassistant

Following the [documentation](http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.2.0/#_severity_of_rules) all constrainst should be checked as severity `MAJOR` and all concepts as `MINOR`.

If I look to the log of my project I found

```
[INFO] Reading rules from directory C:\seu\sandboxes\github\sze_spring\jqassistant
[INFO] Executing group 'default'
[INFO] Executing group 'package:Default'
[INFO] Applying concept 'dependency:Package' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'package:Cycles' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Executing group 'maven:Default'
[INFO] Executing group 'test:Default'
[INFO] Applying concept 'junit4:TestMethod' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'junit4:TestClass' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'test:UnitTestClassName' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Executing group 'layer:Default'
[INFO] Applying concept 'structure:RootPackage' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'layer:Layer' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'layer:LayerDependency.graphml' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'layer:WantedRelations' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'layer:ExistingRelations' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'layer:Cycles' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'layer:ForbiddenRelations' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Executing group 'structure:Default'
[INFO] Applying concept 'structure:Slice' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'structure:SliceDependency.graphml' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'structure:ServiceDependency' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Applying concept 'maven:InternalFile' with severity: 'MINOR'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'structure:RootPackage' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'structure:JobsDependency' with severity: 'INFO'.
[INFO] Validating constraint 'structure:FrontendDependency' with severity: 'INFO'.
```

So it looks to me that the default severity is `INFO` or `MINOR`.

I searched in the whole project for the keyword `severity`, but only find someone in `checkstyle.xml`.

So is it a bug in documentation or missed I something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's indeed a gap between the implementation, a ticket as been created (https://github.com/buschmais/jqa-core-framework/issues/9).

Sorry for the inconvenience.